# Identify manual and programatically button click

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I have one button which works as "**pause**" and "**Resume**". Here user can click this button manually to pause and resume. And somethimes I am performing click programatically using `view.performClick()` method.

The question is....is it possible to know by which click button clicked ?

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am using timer in my app and I want to pause and resume timer.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the click in a different method:

```
private void handleClick(boolean manualClick) {
    //your code...
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    handleClick(true);
}
```

and do not use `view.performClick()` to call it automaically, but call `handleClick(false)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the flag true/false when click manually, and use that while performing click operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(button.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("pause")){
// puse your timer here or whatever you would like

}else{
//resume your time here or whatever you would like
}
```